# Is the American version of the "Father Abraham" song anti-Christian?

Tags: music

In my language, this popular children's song says "The LORD has many children...".

However, I've just learned that the American (maybe the original) version of this song goes like this:

> Father Abraham had many sons
>
> Many sons had Father Abraham
>
> I am one of them and so are you
>
> So let's all praise the Lord.

Isn't it anti-Christian to call Abraham your "Father"? I've been told that the reason Protestants don't use that word to talk about pastors/priests is exactly because Christians shouldn't call anybody but God their "Father" like that.

Comment: Orthodox and Catholic Christians have no issue with addressing the clergy as 'father'. Some Anglicans use the term as well. Perhaps ' inconsistent with Protestant teachings' would be better than 'anti-Christian'

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not a Christian site, but a secular site focused on denominational doctrines. There is a focus here to consider different doctrinal stances, rather than Scripture, to be Christian. Therefore, when addressing issues of concern to Bible believing Christians, you may wan to form your question differently, such as "For those Christians who believe the this verse on 'call no man father' ... How do feel about this song?" I suppose the downvotes are from denominations who don't consider the verse in that light. Maybe also quote the verse for context.

Comment: *The Father of our Country* is what George Washington is called in some figurative language common in America.  *Father Abraham* is a similar (idiomatic or figurative) usage of the word Father and is utterly correct within that kind of usage: he is arguably the Father of all three great Abrahamic faiths: Judaism, Christianity, Islam.  (Consistent with Genesis 17 as well)  Your decision to go with a literal translation may be part of your problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Paul calls the faithful 'sons of Abraham':

> Therefore He who supplies the Spirit to you and works miracles among you, does He do it by the works of the law, or by the hearing of faith? just as Abraham “believed God, and it was accounted to him for righteousness.” Therefore know that only ***those who are of faith are sons of Abraham***. And the Scripture, foreseeing that God would justify the Gentiles by faith, preached the gospel to Abraham beforehand, saying, “In you all the nations shall be blessed.” [Galatians 3:5-8 NKJV]

and refers to Abraham as 'our father Abraham'

> And he received the sign of circumcision, a seal of the righteousness of the faith which he had while still uncircumcised, that he might be the father of all those who believe, though they are uncircumcised, that righteousness might be imputed to them also, and the father of circumcision to those who not only are of the circumcision, but ***who also walk in the steps of the faith which our father Abraham had while still uncircumcised***. [Romans 4:11-12 NJKV]

Given that, it seems reasonable for Christians to refer to Father Abraham. Note that Paul is not referring to Abraham in any clerical manner, but in reference to being part of God's people. I don't think that any Protestant objection to addressing the clergy as 'Father' is relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"Father Abraham" is a construct used by Jesus himself, in the Parable of the rich man and Lazarus, where in Luke 16:24, the rich man uses the term as a form of address for Abraham the Patriarch. I'm not an expert on Aramaic, but I suspect that because of the number of contemporary individuals in the Jewish community at any one time named "Abraham", that "Father Abraham" always refers to the Patriarch, of whom God's promise is recorded in Genesis 17:4, where God makes the covenant with Abram,

> Behold, my covenant is with you, and you shall be the you shall be the father of a multitude of nations.

Just before renaming Abram to Abraham.